# Is ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd truly thread-safe?

Tags: c#, task

I have this piece of code where I want to await on a ongoing task if that task was created for the same input. Here is minimal reproduction of what I'm doing.

```cs
private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task<int>> _tasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task<int>>();

private readonly ExternalService _service;


public async Task SampleTask(){
  var result = await _service.DoSomething();
  await Task.Delay(1000) //this task takes some time do finish
  return result;
}

public async Task<int> DoTask(int key) {
   var task = _tasks.GetOrAdd(key, _ => SampleTask());
   var taskResult = await task;
   _tasks.TryRemove(key, out task);
   return taskResult;
}
```

I'm writing a test to ensure the same task is awaited when multiple requests want to perform the task at (roughly) the same time. I'm doing that by mocking `_service` and counting how many times `_service.DoSomething()` is being called. It should be only once if the calls to `DoTask(int key)` where made at roughly the same time.

However, the results show me that if I call `DoTask(int key)` more than once with a delay between calls of less than 1~2ms, both tasks will create and execute its on instance of `SampleTask()` with the second one replacing the first one in the dictionary.

Considering this, can we say that this method is truly thread-safe? Or isn't my problem a case of thread-safety per se?

Comment: When you call `GetOrAdd()`, the delegate you pass to it can be called multiple times under some circumstances. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: You are also not awaiting `SampleTask()`

Comment: @MatthewWatson, what circunstances would those be?

Comment: @Tseng, do I need to await it in the factory delegate? I'm awaiting it right after it gets assigned to the `task` variable

Comment: @LuísGabrieldeAndrade what are you trying to do in the first place? `ConcurrentDictionary` is thread-safe but that doesn't mean the objects it contains are. It's not a task queue either. If you want to process multiple messages you should probably use `ActionBlock<T>` or the other classes in the TPL DataflowBlock library. Another good option would be to use `System.Threading.Channels` to implement pub/sub workers.

Comment: @LuísGabrieldeAndrade ConcurrentDictionary and ConcurrentQueue are probably used by both Dataflow and Channels to implement their buffers deep down. There's a lot more to creating a pub/sub or async worker queue than the buffer though

Comment: [From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.7.2): `If you call GetOrAdd simultaneously on different threads, valueFactory may be called multiple times, but only one key/value pair will be added to the dictionary.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have this computation-intensive task to execute that may be called more than once at roughly the same time for the same input. I don't want to perform this task more than once simultaneously for the same input because it will yield the same result.

Comment: @LuísGabrieldeAndrade that's a very different question and still can't be implemented just with ConcurrentDictionary. It's available through Reactive Extensions though, as the `Throttle` operator. You can create an Observable or Subject that receives messages from multiple sources, eg multiple form submits, or multiple users submitting the same thing, put `Throttel(Timespan.FromSeconds(60).Subscribe(...)` to ensure that the task called by `subscribe` is only called once every 60 seconds

Comment: @LuísGabrieldeAndrade when I say different question, it's closer to different problem domain. Concurrent collections deal only with concurrent data modification of collections. You are asking about the behaviour of event streams though. *Maybe* you can use one to implement the other, but you still have to solve that *other* problem.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, thank you for pointing out that part of the docs. I guess I overlooked that part. My bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_GetOrAdd__0_System_Func__0__1__) (emphasis mine):

> For modifications and write operations to the dictionary, [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) uses fine-grained locking to ensure thread safety. (Read operations on the dictionary are performed in a lock-free manner.) However, the `valueFactory` delegate is called outside the locks to avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a lock. Therefore, [`GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.7.2) is not atomic with regards to all other operations on the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` class.
>
> Since a key/value can be inserted by another thread while `valueFactory` is generating a value, you cannot trust that just because `valueFactory` executed, its produced value will be inserted into the dictionary and returned. **If you call `GetOrAdd` simultaneously on different threads, `valueFactory` may be called multiple times, but only one key/value pair will be added to the dictionary.**

So while the dictionary is properly thread-safe, calls to the `valueFactory`, or `_ => SampleTask()` in your case, are not guaranteed to be unique. So your factory function should be able to live with that fact.

You can confirm this [from the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,1059):

```csharp
public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
{
    if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    if (valueFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("valueFactory");

    TValue resultingValue;
    if (TryGetValue(key, out resultingValue))
    {
        return resultingValue;
    }
    TryAddInternal(key, valueFactory(key), false, true, out resultingValue);
    return resultingValue;
}
```

As you can see, `valueFactory` is being called outside of `TryAddInternal` which is responsible of locking the dictionary properly.

However, since `valueFactory` is a lambda function that returns a task in your case (`_ => SampleTask()`), and the dictionary will not await that task itself, the function will finish *quickly* and just return the incomplete `Task` after encountering the first `await` (when the async state machine is set up). So unless the calls are very quickly after another, the task should be added very quickly to the dictionary and subsequent calls will reuse the same task.

If you require this to happen just once in *all* cases, you should consider locking on the task creation yourself. Since it will finish quickly (regardless of how long your task actually takes to resolve), locking will not hurt that much.