# How does this ConcurrentDictionary + Lazy<Task<T>> code work?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, concurrentdictionary

<del>There's [various](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815298/30674) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814980/is-concurrentdictionary-getoradd-truly-thread-safe)/[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54118193/30674) that say that the .NET/.NET Core's `ConcurrentDictionary` `GetOrAdd` method is not thread-safe when the `Func` delegate is used to calculate the value to insert into the dictionary, if the key didn't already exist.</del>

I'm under the belief that when using the factory method of a `ConcurrentDictionary`'s `GetOrAdd` method, it could be called multiple times "at the same time/in really quick succession" if a number of requests occur at the "same time". This could be wasteful, especially if the call is "expensive". (@panagiotis-kanavos explains this better than I). With this assumption, I'm struggling to understand how some sample code I made, seems to work.

I've [created a working sample on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/viWgjA) but I'm stuck trying to understand how it works.

A common <del>recommendation</del> suggestion/idea I've read is to have a `Lazy<Task<T>>` value in the `ConcurrentDictionary`. The idea is that the `Lazy` prevents other calls from executing the underlying method.

The main part of the code which does the heavy lifting is this:

```
    public static async Task<DateTime> GetDateFromCache()
    {
        var result = await _cache.GetOrAdd("someDateTime", new Lazy<Task<DateTime>>(async () => 
        {
            // NOTE: i've made this method take 2 seconds to run, each time it's called.
            var someData = await GetDataFromSomeExternalDependency();
            
            return DateTime.UtcNow;
            
        })).Value;
        
        return result;
    }
```

This is how I read this:

- Check if `someDateTime` key exists in the dictionary.
- If yes, return that. <-- That's a thread-safe atomic action. Yay!
- If no, then here we go ....
- Create an instance of a `Lazy<Task<DateTime>>` (which is basically instant)
- Return that `Lazy` instance. (so far, the actual 'expensive' operation hasn't been called, yet.)
- Now get the `Value`, which is a `Task<DateTime>`.
- Now `await` this task .. which finally does the 'expensive' call. It waits 2 seconds .. and then returns the result (some point in Time).

Now this is where I'm all wrong. Because I'm assuming (above) that the value in the key/value is a `Lazy<Task<DateTime>>` ... which the `await` would call each time. If the `await` is called, one at a time (because the `Lazy` protects other callers from all calling at the same time) then I would have though that the result would a different `DateTime` with each independent call.

So can someone please explain where I'm wrong in my thinking, please?

(please refer to the full running code in .NET Fiddler).

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary GetOrAdd method is not thread-safe when` that's not what those answers say at all

Comment: What they say is that the *factory method*, while thread-safe, isn't guaranteed to produce just a single result if called multiple times concurrently.  If that happens, only one of the values will be used

Comment: Does asking for the value of a `Task` run it again, in your view? Why / why not? `which the await would call each time.` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @00110001 `Your lazy code would need to be an instance method, using it like is jsut making the existing problem worse` I don't think it is making the problem worse if it ensures it runs only once.

Comment: `which the await would call each time` that's not the case. A Task is an already-active *promise*, not a function pointer. Calling `await` doesn't run the promise, it awaits for it to produce a result. Calling `await` multiple times won't run the task again, it will return the first result

Comment: @mjwills are yes i didnt see the bracket, even still, this is suspect

Comment: I don't think it is suspect @00110001. I mean, `AsyncLazy` may be better (since `Result` may deadlock). And I'd use `LazyWithNoExceptionCaching` over `Lazy` as a general rule. But other than that the code does what I expect.

Comment: As for `Lazy`, it's not really needed for lazy evaluation - when you call `GetDateFromCache` you want the answer *now*. `ConcurrentDictionary` doesn't have async factory methods though so `Lazy` is used to turn the asynchronous factory method into a synchronous object. Essentially, it synchronizes possible concurrent factory calls

Comment: `(because the Lazy protects other callers from all calling at the same time) ... with each independent call.` Lazy ensures it gets called successfully only once (and by default ensures only one attempt occurs at a given point in time). The first run succeeded, so each subsequent call doesn't even occur. Asking for the `Result` of a completed task doesn't _do_ anything. It just serves up the same value again. And if it isn't completed (inflight) it just blocks until it is ready. Which is consistent with https://dotnetfiddle.net/SS3NJH .

Comment: This technique can be improved if you use one of the many AsyncLazy implementations like [this one](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLazy). A Lazy doesn't know about tasks, which is why you need to await its `Value` to get a `Task<>` instead of a `Task<Task<>>`

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos and @mjwills for spending time on my question - really appreciate it both. So in summary, is it fair to say the code provided is Okay? It can be made better (read: simpler to read) with @stephencleary 's `AsyncLazy` .. but it still _works_ okay?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Basically yes. It will work (if it doesn't deadlock).

Comment: Who ever downvoted, please explain why? I'm asking an honest question to why my understanding of some code, is not what is happening. Shees!

Comment: Fixed up the OP to hopefully reflect my understanding, learning from all of this.

Answer (score 3):

> Because I'm assuming (above) that the value in the key/value is a `Lazy<Task<DateTime>>`

Yes, that is true.

> which the await would call each time. If the await is called, one at a time (because the Lazy protects other callers from all calling at the same time) then I would have though that the result would a different DateTime with each independent call.

await is not a call, it is more like "continue execution when the result is available". Accessing `Lazy.Value` will create the task, and this will initiate the call to the `GetDataFromSomeExternalDependency` that eventually returns the DateTime. You can await the task however many times you want and get the same result.