# ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd nested collections

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I've read this question, but I still don't understand how `GetOrAdd` works if I have a nested collection.

[Is ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd truly thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814980/is-concurrentdictionary-getoradd-truly-thread-safe)

If I haven't created a nested collection yet, and `GetOrAdd` is called simultaneously from multiple threads, what happens?
I expect the behavior that only one of the threads will be able to create a new collection, and the rest will receive the one already created and add a value there. Is this how it's going to happen?

```
var completions = subscribers.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new ConcurrentBag<TaskCompletionSource<string>>());
completions.Add(completion);
```

Comment: The behaviour isn't any different for collections than for other types. The delegate you pass for the factory can be called multiple times concurrently, but only one thread can "win" the race. The values for the other threads will simply be discarded. This can be bad for disposable types, since they'll leak, but `ConcurrentBag` isn't, so you can just leave it to be garbage collected. When `GetOrAdd` returns, it will then always return the same collection for everyone.

Comment: A classic solution is using the `Lazy` class, see: https://endjin.com/blog/2015/10/using-lazy-and-concurrentdictionary-to-ensure-a-thread-safe-run-once-lazy-loaded-collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect the behavior that only one of the threads will be able to create a new collection,

Not exactly. It is entirely possible that more than one threads will create a new `TValue`, but only one of these `TValue`s will be added in the dictionary. The other `TValue`s will fall out of scope and will be discarded (garbage-collected).

> and the rest will receive the one already created and add a value there.

Yes, all threads will interact with the same `TValue`. The [`GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd) returns the `TValue` created by the thread that won the optimistic locking race. The race is optimistic because the `valueFactory` delegate is called outside the locks used internally by the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` collection. This collection doesn't allow pessimistic locking, i.e. you can't use its internal locks for protecting your own code. Pessimistic locking could be beneficial in some scenarios, but this feature is simply not supported by this collection.